# esp8266 client and server at the same time

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I need to program an esp8266 to do the following:

1. connect to a wifi network (station mode only)
2. start a server (udp) process to service requests
3. start a client (udp) to send roughly every 60 seconds

I am thinking on doing these actions on the setup() function:

1. create a timer to be triggered every 60 seconds.
2. start the udp server.

The idea is to "interrupt" the server with the timer and using the same port used on the server to send a udp packet to a remote location.
Example:
server is started to listen on port 2000. Then when the interrupt is triggered, the server should "pause", then we should send a packet from port 2000 to our remote IP, then the server should "resume"

I am waiting for my board to arrive to test this setup but wanted to know if that is possible. I am assuming that the mqtt client should work similarly (it can subscribe and publish). Aside from an interrupt I can't think on another way to "stop" the server temporarily and act as a client

Has anybody tried this before?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `AT` command

```
AT+CIPMUX=1
```

and

```
AT+CIPSTART=<link ID>,<type>,<remote IP>,<remote port>[,<TCP keep alive>]<link ID>
```

Comment: I'm afraid AT command is not relevant here. ESP8266 when working with Arduino IDE can run the sketch itself, and doesn't have to be communicated from another board using AT commands.